# Firebase date range query

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to get data based on a certain date range using `startAt()` and `endAt()`.
The data is set with timestamp priority.

My structure looks like this:

```
"sessions" : {
    "1413099157" : {
      ".priority" : 1413099338,
      "max_position" : "100",
      "unique" : "1",
      "views" : "1"
    },
    "1413105026" : {
      ".priority" : 1413105210,
      "max_position" : "100",
      "unique" : "1",
      "views" : "1"
    },
    "1413105029" : {
      ".priority" : 1413105210,
      "max_position" : "100",
      "unique" : "1",
      "views" : "1"
    },
    "1413105035" : {
      ".priority" : 1413105219,
      "max_position" : "100",
      "unique" : "1",
      "views" : "1"
    },
    "2818847947" : {
      ".priority" : 1413099248,
      "max_position" : "100:quiet",
      "views" : "3"
    }
}
```

And my query:

```
fbRef.child('sessions').on('value', function(session) {
    var sessions = session.val();
    for (var sess in sessions) {
        fbRef.child('sessions/'+sess)
            .startAt(1412538604)
            .endAt(1413143404)
            .on('value', function(sess_data) {
                 console.log('Object: ', sess_data.val());
                 console.log('Priority: '+sess_data.getPriority());
        });
    };
});
```

I get null for both the value and the priority:
[image: Console.log() outputs]

Query is working good if I remove the `startAt()` and `endAt()`.

I've been looking for an answer for a while and couldn't find any solution for this, not sure what is the problem...

Will be glad for any help!

Comment: Please either remove the PHP code from the questions (and fill in the actual values that are being used in your JavaScript code) or add a PHP tag to the question.

Comment: Ok, done. Replaced it with actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've chosen the code construct above, but this seems a lot simpler and works without a problem:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://yourfirebase.firebaseio.com/');
ref.child('sessions')
  .startAt(1413105210)
  .endAt(1413105219)
  .on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.exportVal());
  });
```

See http://jsbin.com/qunonu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Interesting...I guess i'm missing some core concepts :/ Will check that again. Anyway I have some issue with an aggregation I need to do, I want to count the number of max_position grouped by the position (0, 25, 50, 75, 100). Any ideas? Firebase is ready for such kind of queries?

Comment: Didn't find anything about the grouped counting and I read Firebase docs few times and also searched more info on the web. I'll post a new question about it. Thanks!